# javascript implementing error

Tags: javascript, html

I am just codeing a little quiz to teach a friend html and javascript basics. I got html and javascript all w/o syntax errors or something. The javascript is parseble and all debugging tools I have aren´t finding the error. The questions are in german, but that is irrelevant.
Here is the code:
html
every question looks about that in the h1 tag the question, the div has an id with the question number and all answers are in a tags and also have their number as id.

```
<div id="questionOne" style="display:none;">
    <h1>
        Von wo aus kann man nur nach S&uuml;den gehen?
    </h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id="questionOneAnswerOne">Norpol</a> <br> <!--Richtig-->
    <a id="questionOneAnswerTwo">S&uuml;dpol</a> <br>
    <a id="questionOneAnswerThree">&Auml;quator</a> <br>
```

I implented the javascipt like this:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
```

The script is like the following:
first I define a variable like this for every answer

```
var questionOneAnswerOne = document.getElementById("questionOneAnswerOne");
```

than the right answer gets a code like this

```
questionOneAnswerOne.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Right!");
    document.getElementById("questionOne").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("questionTwo").style.display="block";
};
```

which just hides the just completed and shows the next question

after that all wrong answers get a code like this

```
questionOneAnswerTwo.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Wrong!");
    location.reload();
};
```

which forces the entire side to reload and than you are back at the start

older versions of this code worked very well and I don´t know what happened.

Here is the entire code
javascript:

```
    //Go!
document.getElementById("go").onclick=function(){
    console.log("Let the games begin!");
};
//One
var questionOneAnswerOne = document.getElementById("questionOneAnswerOne");
var questionOneAnswerTwo = document.getElementById("questionOneAnswerTwo");
var questionOneAnswerThree = document.getElementById("questionOneAnswerThree");
var questionOneAnswerFour = document.getElementById("questionOneAnswerFour")
//Two
var questionTwoAnswerOne = document.getElementById("questionTwoAnswerOne");
var questionTwoAnswerTwo = document.getElementById("questionTwoAnswerTwo");
var questionTwoAnswerThree = document.getElementById("questionTwoAnswerThree");
var questionTwoAnswerFour = document.getElementById("questionTwoAnswerFour")
//Three
var questionThreeAnswerOne = document.getElementById("questionThreeAnswerOne");
var questionThreeAnswerTwo = document.getElementById("questionThreeAnswerTwo");
var questionThreeAnswerThree = document.getElementById("questionThreeAnswerThree");
var questionThreeAnswerFour = document.getElementById("questionThreeAnswerFour")
//Four
var questionFourAnswerOne = document.getElementById("questionFourAnswerOne");
var questionFourAnswerTwo = document.getElementById("questionFourAnswerTwo");
var questionFourAnswerThree = document.getElementById("questionFourAnswerThree");
var questionFourAnswerFour = document.getElementById("questionFourAnswerFour")


//richtige Antwort (german for right answer)
questionOneAnswerOne.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Right!");
    document.getElementById("questionOne").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("questionTwo").style.display="block";
};

questionTwoAnswerFour.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Right!");
    document.getElementById("questionTwo").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("questionThree").style.display="inline";
};

questionThreeAnswerTwo.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Right!");
    document.getElementById("questionThree").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("questionFour").style.display="inline";
};

questionFourAnswerThree.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Right!");
    document.getElementById("questionFour").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("questionFive").style.display="inline";
};



//falsche Antwort (german for wrong answer)
//One
questionOneAnswerTwo.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Wrong!");
    location.reload();
};

questionOneAnswerThree.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Wrong!");
    location.reload();
};

questionOneAnswerFour.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Wrong!");
    location.reload();
};
//Two
questionTwoAnswerOne.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Wrong!");
    doculocation.reload();
};

questionTwoAnswerTwo.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Wrong!");
    location.reload();
};

questionTwoAnswerThree.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Wrong!");
    location.reload();
};
//Three
questionThreeAnswerOne.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Wrong!");
    doculocation.reload();
};

questionThreeAnswerThree.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Wrong!");
    location.reload();
};

questionThreeAnswerFour.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Wrong!");
    location.reload();
}
//Four
questionFourAnswerOne.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Wrong!");
    doculocation.reload();
};

questionFourAnswerTwo.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Wrong!");
    location.reload();
};

questionFourAnswerFour.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Wrong!");
    location.reload();
}

//Start
//go.onclick = function() {
//  console.log("Let the games begin!")
//  document.getElementById("startScreen").style.display="none";
//  document.getElementById("questionOne").style.display="inline";
//};
```

and this is the html (it contains some emty divs for new questions):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="startScreen">
        <h1>
            WELCOME TO THE 100 QUESTION GAME!
        </h1>

        <h2 id="go" style="color:pink">
            Lets GO!
        </h2>
        <p>
            by strawberry studios
        </p>

    </div>

    <div id="questionOne" style="display:none;">
        <h1>
            Von wo aus kann man nur nach S&uuml;den gehen?
        </h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a id="questionOneAnswerOne">Norpol</a> <br> <!--Richtig-->
        <a id="questionOneAnswerTwo">S&uuml;dpol</a> <br>
        <a id="questionOneAnswerThree">&Auml;quator</a> <br>
        <a id="questionOneAnswerFour">Bayern</a> <br>
    </div>

    <div id="questionTwo" style="display:none;">
        <h1>
            Was ist am teuersten?
        </h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a id="questionTwoAnswerOne">Diamant</a> <br>
        <a id="quoestionTwonswerTwo">Platin</a> <br>
        <a id="questionTwoAnswerThree">Gold</a> <br>
        <a id="questionTwoAnswerFour">Osmium<a/> <br> <!--Richtig-->
    </div>

    <div id="questionThree" style="display:none;">
        <h1>
            Wof&uulm;r steht HTML?
        </h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a id="questionThreeAnswerOne">Hyper Text Multiple Language</a> <br>
        <a id="questionThreenswerTwo">Hyper Text Markup Language</a> <br> <!--Richtig-->
        <a id="questionThreeAnswerThree">Hydrotecinmultiliquid</a> <br>
        <a id="questionThreeAnswerFour">Hype The Mother (a)lLong<a/> <br>
    </div>

    <div id="questionFour" style="display:none;">
        <h1>
            Welche Farbe h&auml;tte Cola ohne Farbstoffe?
        </h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a id="questionFourAnswerOne">Gelb</a> <br>
        <a id="questionFouranswerTwo">Erdbraun</a> <br>
        <a id="questionFourAnswerThree">Grün</a> <br> <!--Richtig-->
        <a id="questionFourAnswerFour">Türkis<a/> <br>
    </div>

    <div id="questionFive" style="display:none;">

    </div>

    <div id="questionSix" style="display:none;">

    </div>

    <div id="questionSeven" style="display:none;">

    </div>

    <div id="questionEight" style="display:none;">

    </div>

    <div id="questionNine" style="display:none;">

    </div>

    <div id="questionTen" style="display:none;">

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Maybe I missed something but...what is the problem?

Comment: What is your problem? Also can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: questions are not appearing?

Comment: "older versions of this code worked very well and I don´t know what happened."  Was there ever a louder cry for using a [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) and [diffing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly and the questions aren't appearing after pressing the go button, than you seem to be missing some code in the event:

```
//Go!
document.getElementById("go").onclick=function(){
    console.log("Let the games begin!");
};
```

it should be rather:

```
//Go!
document.getElementById("go").onclick=function(){
    console.log("Let the games begin!");
    document.getElementById("go").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("questionOne").style.display="block";
};
```

At least as far as I can tell from your code, questionOne is set to `display="none"` initially and I couldn't find a javascript code which would set it to `display="block"`

Comment: year now I saw it too. xD sry for wasteing your time